# Modify Search Block HTML Output for Zurb Foundation Topbar

Tags: search

I have created a subtheme from the Zurb Foundation base theme for Drupal 7.

I am trying to:

- Add "data-equalizer" and "data-equalizer-watch" to the html output of the core Search Form Block.
- Change the Search button text to a glyph-icon
- Add/Remove some classes from the Search Button
- Change the column sizes

Unfortunately, it currently appears to look like this with a simple markup:
[image]

The current HTML output looks like this:

```
<div class="row collapse">
<div class="small-8 columns">
    <div class="form-item form-type-textfield form-item-search-block-form">
        <label class="element-invisible" for="edit-search-block-form--2">Search </label>
        <input title="Enter the terms you wish to search for." type="text" id="edit-search-block-form--2" name="search_block_form" value="" size="15" maxlength="128" class="form-text">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="small-4 columns"><button class="secondary button radius postfix expand form-submit" id="edit-submit--3" name="op" value="Search" type="submit">Search</button>
</div>
```

When building my own test form with HTML and CSS (for design purposes), I was able to achieve the desired look for my search in the topbar in a dropdown that appeared like this:

[image]

The code I used for that is here:

```
<div class="row collapse" data-equalizer>
<div class="small-10 columns">
    <input type="text" name="search_block_form" placeholder="Search..." id="nav-input" class="postfix" data-equalizer-watch>
</div>
<div class="small-2 columns">
    <button name="op" id="nav-button" class="postfix"><i class="step fi-magnifying-glass size-72" data-equalizer-watch></i></button >
</div>
```

The current html output of the Drupal Search Block Form also adds the classes "secondary" and "radius" and I want to remove those.

I know what I want the html output to look like but am unsure as to how to make the output exactly what I want it to be.

I have looked online at several different theme hooks but none seem to do the trick and have limited to me.